# Assign first element of groupby to a column yields NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Why does this not work out?

I get the right results if I just print it out, but if I use the same to assign it to the df column, I get Nan values...

```
print(df.groupby('cumsum').first()['Date'])

cumsum
1     2021-01-05 11:00:00
2     2021-01-06 08:00:00
3     2021-01-06 10:00:00
4     2021-01-06 13:00:00
5     2021-01-06 14:00:00
              ...        
557   2021-08-08 08:00:00
558   2021-08-08 09:00:00
559   2021-08-08 11:00:00
560   2021-08-08 13:00:00
561   2021-08-08 18:00:00
Name: Date, Length: 561, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

vs

```
df["Date_First"] = df.groupby('cumsum').first()['Date']

Date
2021-01-01 00:00:00   NaT
2021-01-01 01:00:00   NaT
2021-01-01 02:00:00   NaT
2021-01-01 03:00:00   NaT
2021-01-01 04:00:00   NaT
                       ..
2021-08-08 14:00:00   NaT
2021-08-08 15:00:00   NaT
2021-08-08 16:00:00   NaT
2021-08-08 17:00:00   NaT
2021-08-08 18:00:00   NaT
Name: Date_Last, Length: 5268, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What happens here?

I used an exmpmle form here, but want to get the first elements.
https://www.codeforests.com/2021/03/30/group-consecutive-rows-in-pandas/

Comment: `df.groupby('cumsum')['Date'].transform("first")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What happens here?**

If use:

```
print(df.groupby('cumsum')['Date'].first())
#print(df.groupby('cumsum').first()['Date'])
```

output are aggregated values by column `cumsum` with aggregated function `first`.

So in index are unique values `cumsum`, so if assign to new column there is mismatch with original index and output are `NaN`s.

---

Solution is use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), which repeat aggregated values to Series (column) with same size like original DataFrame, so index is same like original and assign working perfectly:

```
df["Date_First"] = df.groupby('cumsum')['Date'].transform("first")
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is the difference between the first tweo line of code you posted, where you commented out the second one. first and 'Date' are interchanged?

Comment: @c_data Difference is if use first solution there is used `first` function only for `Date` column, in second is used for al columns and then filtered column `Date`. First solution is more panda-nic, more common.